# 3.3V digital signal as input to Arduino mega 2560

Tags: arduino

[image]I am using arduino mega 2560. I know it reads digital input signal of 5V as high but could any one tell me whether it takes 3.3V digital input as high or not? And what is the minimum value it guarantees to read as high?

Comment: Just FYI. There is a stack dedicated to Arduino http://arduino.stackexchange.com

Comment: Why not just eliminate R3, turn on the internal pullup in the ATMega2560, and not worry about it?

Comment: In addition to what Matt said, if there's a concern with the 3.3V pullup, why not just use 5V for the pullup, since the Arduino supplies both? Furthermore, with the LM324 running on 5V, you could connect the LM324 output direct to the Arduino, and eliminate the transistor altogether. The sense of the signal would be inverted, but if that's a problem then swap the LM324 inputs.

Comment: Actually the arduino is further interfaced with simulink which has no support for arduino mega and due to use its internal pull-up resistors. Thats why R3 is used as external pullup resistor....

Comment: Actually the circuit shown above is meant to work both with arduino mega 2560 and arduino due. And due only operates at 3.3V not at 5V so 3.3V pull-up is used rather than 5V.

Comment: And I tested the circuit yesterday and fortunately it works fine both with arduino mega and arduino due... Thanks for the help..

Answer (score 5):

You just need to refer to the [ATmega 2560 datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-2549-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega640-1280-1281-2560-2561_datasheet.pdf)

Page 355, electrical characteristics

[image]

> Notes:
>   1."Max" means the highest value where the pin is guaranteed to be read as low.
>   2."Min" means the lowest value where the pin is guaranteed to be read as high.

For Vcc=5V:

The LOW level is below  \$ 0.3 \times V_{cc} = 0.3 \times 5V = 1.5V\$

The HIGH level is above \$ 0.6 \times V_{cc} = 0.6 \times 5V = 3V \$

If your sensor (or whatever the source of the voltage is) can actually deliver 3.3V then you are fine, but if the voltage is actually close to 3V then you'll be in trouble.

Comment: The source provides 3.27V. So I guess it would be fine according to the formula you mentioned above??

Comment: @user40019 Yes, if the "source" can provide 3.27V then you will be fine, but note that depending of the "source" drive ability and possible load connected (apart from the AVR input which is high impedance) the voltage may actually drop, so make sure that it's in the level you describe.

Comment: Yes, I tested the circuit today and it works fine with arduino mega 2560.. Thanks for the help..

Answer (score 2):

From the Atmega640/1280/1281/2560/2561 datasheet:

> V<sub>IH</sub> Input High Voltage, Except XTAL1 and RESET pins (V<sub>CC</sub> = 2.4V - 5.5V ) | Min: 0.6V<sub>CC</sub>

At a V<sub>CC</sub> of 5.0V that means 3.0V. The 3.3V output will marginally meet the minimum, and that's with almost no loading; more loading means a lower high output voltage. Either use a level converter or run the Arduino at a lower voltage instead.

Comment: The input voltage(supply voltage) range of arduino mega 2560 is 7-20V. So what do you refer Vcc to? Is Vcc the same as the supply voltage. Here is the link for arduino mega 2560 page: http://arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardMega2560

Comment: Vcc is the supply voltage *to the MCU*. This is the voltage *after* the on-board regulator, and is the "Operating Voltage" as listed on that page.

Comment: So how could we change that voltage with arduino? because i guess we only supply voltage to arduino board not the MCU.....

Comment: You can apply a separate voltage to the "5V" pin instead of through USB or barrel jack. Note that this will change the voltage on the 5V pin for *all shields*, which may have consequences for them as well. You may also need to enable the prescaler in order to reduce the clock speed as per the "Speed Grades" subsection in the "Electrical Characteristics" section of the datasheet.

Comment: Or is it possible that I pull up specific digital input pin externally to 3.3V with some resistor in between? Then that 3.3V would be Vcc for MCU??

Comment: Some boards have a mechanism for changing the voltage connected to Vcc. After checking the schematic I can say that the Arduino Mega does not.

Comment: Ok. In short if my source provides 3.3V digital input , Arduino mega 2560 would consider it high according to the formula you mentioned above. Thats what I wanted to confirm.

Comment: I would still use a level converter so that noise wouldn't be an issue. What bandwidth does the signal need, i.e. how quickly does it change?

Comment: 1Khz at maximum

Comment: In that case you can use either a NPN transistor with the collector connected to an input pin (which will invert the signal) or something like a [SN74LVC1G07](http://www.ti.com/product/sn74lvc1g07) with a 3.3V supply. In both cases you'll need to have the pullup on the input pin enabled.

Comment: I am using NPN transistor BC547 with collector connected to input pin with 3.3V supply. And that input pin is pulled up externally with 3.3V supply(the same which connects with collector).

Comment: Towards the MCU, or towards the device? Perhaps you should add a schematic to the question.

Comment: I just added schematic diagram above. Please have a look at that....

Comment: This is the circuit designed to work both with Arduino mega 2560 which operates at 5V and with arduino due which operates at 3.3V.

Comment: It works fine with arduino due that requires 3.3V at its input pins. but I was confused about its operation with arduino mega 2560.

Comment: If you can modify it at all then you should tie the output stage to 5V instead. It will then work perfectly with the Mega.

Comment: But then it would not work with Arduino due.... Right??

Comment: This one circuit is meant to be worked with both arduino boards...

Comment: Correct. The Due inputs are not 5V-tolerant.

Comment: Actually i want to make it work with both the arduino boards... Thats the constraint....

Comment: Any how, I'l try out this stuff tomorrow in the lab and update you about the result....

Comment: In that case you'll need to change the Mega part, either reducing the Vcc or adding a level converter.

Comment: I tested the schematic that I uploaded above yesterday, it works fine.... It is working fine with both the arduino mega 2560 and due...

Comment: Because there's very little noise in your current environment.